# Converting Recursion into Into Iteration

Tags: recursion

While reading **Code Complete** second edition, I came across this line:

> You can do anything with stacks and iteration that you can do with
>   recursion.

Is this true? or there are functions, that must be implemented recursively, and can't be done otherwise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU uses stacks and iteration to run *any* program, including programs based on recursion.

If you are unsure how this works, I suggest picking up an appropriate textbook.

Comment: I'm talking at a higher level, for example, can the C language be used to implement any recursive function, in an iterative way? because recursive functions, though sometimes they look simple an elegant, they might eat a lot of memory stack, and might cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Recursive functions are implemented on actual hardware using a stack. You can't escape this.

Comment: Also, actual computers can also run out of heap space. When we say that stacks and iteration can simulate recursion, we consider an idealized computer.